# How to get excel to pick the winner from a column of scores?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet setup where I will be entering a set of scores throughout the day for teams.  I have excel finding the scores I want for the 1st-third place and it will output the score.  The problem is I want it to tell me the team, not the score.  In my sheet, I have a list of scores in say column B2-B30.  The teams are listed in column A2-A30.  I want the program to find the max score in B and relate that to the team name in A and output the team name along with the score.

Comment: We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have no idea where to start with the script, though.  Any ideas where to go start looking?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17929425/367865) describes how to get the label of the highest value in a set:

`=INDEX(A1:A4,MATCH(MAX(B1:B4),B1:B4,0))`

[This forum thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/18244-how-do-i-find-second-highest-value-series.html) describes how to get the second highest value in a set:

`=LARGE(A1:A4,2)`

So putting them together and matching up with your example:

- First: `=INDEX(A2:A30,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B30,1),B2:B30,0))`
- Second: `=INDEX(A2:A30,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B30,2),B2:B30,0))`
- Third: `=INDEX(A2:A30,MATCH(LARGE(B2:B30,3),B2:B30,0))`